# Can you play gifs on android using the ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I am building an app using the ionic framework and the app has/uses a ton of gifs all over the place. Will I have an issues when publishing to android?

Comment: I don't think so. Why should they deny an app including gifs?

Comment: haha I sure hope not...I meant would the gifs still work as many people have told me gifs are not supported on android

Comment: Just try, i just use one gif in my application. But I never had some troubles.